# load data local infile ,importing csv to mysql table not working properly

Tags: mysql

I am using load data infile to import data from csv to mysql table, but data is not inserted properly,

in the csv file fields are enclosed by ", e.g. "field1","field2","field3"
some fields consist of multiple lines..

here is my script..

load data local infile 'my.csv' into table mytable
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried on MySQL 5.5, it works, even if some fields consist of multiple lines.

Try to use '\r\n' as a line separator.